# war file deployment error from glassfish 4.1 admin console

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

In my project (created in **Netbeans 8**), we have to create a war file and deploy on different machine, from **Glassfish 4.1 admin console**.

Same process i.e deploying the war file from **Glassfish 4.1** (opened from **Netbeans 8**) worked fine  on our local machine on which the project is developed (in **Netbeans**).

> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error
>   creating managed object for class: class
>   org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener. Please see
>   server.log for more details.

**Server log::**

> java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error
>   creating managed object for class: class
>   org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)    at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: please see the server log details mentioned as part of question

Comment: Did you try to deploy the application before on the remote server? Maybe you have to restart the server before deploying again.

Comment: I built the application in netbeans 8 and deployed into the embeded glassfish 4.1 server on my machine,worked fine there, but since it is finally to be deployed on the remote machine , so i have been trying to deploy the war file on other machine through glassfish 4.1, so that i am getting the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem. However I'm attempting to deploy to AIX 6.1, which may be the source of the problem for me.

In prior versions of Glassfish, Oracle released a separate version of Glassfish to run on AIX machines due to the differences between IBM Java and Oracle Java. Since there is not a separate version of Glassfish 4.1 for AIX, I suspect that my efforts to get it to operate on AIX will be in vain.

In my case I've been experimenting with the jaxws-rt-2.2.6-6.jar and rt.jar (from Oracle Java 1.7.0_21) and seeing if adding them to the classpath within Glassfish 4.1 will allow me to generate some other error, if not fix the problem. Having a real tough time determining if Glassfish is able to see those libraries (I assume no since I keep getting the same error).

Anyhow, if you're still having the same problem, you might want to state what OS you were developing on and what OS you're attempting to deploy to. That might shed more light on the problem.